# Struggling to compare number of sides to determine shape type

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Looking to determine shape type by sides (number) passed in .. code below only goes to first index, triangle .. my guess is because I'm not properly comparing sides number to sides property in array? I tried using `filter`, `forEach`, and `map` and ran into rabbit hole. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
var Shape = function(sides) {
  this.sides = sides;

  if (this.sides < 3 || typeof(this.sides) !== 'number'){
    this.sides = null;
  }
};
Shape.prototype.getType = function(sides){
  var shapes = [{type: "triangle", sides: 3}, {type: "quadrilateral", sides: 4}, {type: "pentagon", sides: 5}, {type: "hexagon", sides:6}, {type: "heptagon", sides: 7}, {type: "octagon", sides: 8}, {type: "nonagon", sides: 9}, {type: "decagon", sides: 10}];

  for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++){
    console.log(shapes[i].sides);
    var sideExists = shapes.indexOf(shapes[i].sides) > -1;
    if (sides === sideExists){
      return shapes[i].type;
    }else{
      return 'Could not determine type';
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `indexOf` like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop seems to need to compare the sides parameter to the sides in the shapes array, something more like this:

```
Shape.prototype.getType = function(sides){
  var shapes = [{type: "triangle", sides: 3}, {type: "quadrilateral", sides: 4}, {type: "pentagon", sides: 5}, {type: "hexagon", sides:6}, {type: "heptagon", sides: 7}, {type: "octagon", sides: 8}, {type: "nonagon", sides: 9}, {type: "decagon", sides: 10}];

  for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++){

    if (sides === shapes[i].sides){
      return shapes[i].type;
    }
  }

  return 'Could not determine type';
};
```

Comment: Thank you @fordareh it worked, I just had to make 'sides' in if statement 'this.sides' .. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I would probably prefer doing like this.

```js
var Shape = function(sides) {
  (sides < 3 || typeof sides !== 'number') ? this.sides = 0 : this.sides = Math.floor(sides);
};

Shape.prototype.getType = function(){
  var shapes = {0: "not defined shape", 3: "triangle", 4: "quadrilateral", 5: "pentagon", 6: "hexagon", 7: "heptagon", 8: "octagon", 9: "nonagon", 10: "decagon"};
  return shapes[this.sides];
}

var square = new Shape(7);
document.write("<pre> I am a " + square.getType() + "</pre>");
```